# Python-docx: Editing a pre-existing Run

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('CLT.docx')
test = doc.paragraphs[12].runs[2].text
print(test)
doc.save(input('Name of docx file? Make sure to add file extension '))
```

I've trying to figure out some way to add/edit text to a pre-existing run using python-docx. I've tried test.clear() just to see if I can remove it,  but that doesn't seem to work. Additionally, I tried test.add_run('test') and that didn't work either. I know how to add a new run but it will only add it at the end of the paragraph which doesn't help me much. Currently, 'print' will output the text i'd like to alter within the document, "TERMOFINTERNSHIP". Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of a run can be edited in its entirety. So to replace "ac" with "abc" you just do something like this:

```
>>> run.text
"ac"
>>> run.text = "abc"
>>> run.text
"abc"
```

You cannot simply insert characters at some location; you need to extract the text, edit that `str` value using Python `str` methods, and replace it entirely. In a way of thinking, the "editing" is done *outside* `python-docx` and you're simply using `python-docx` for the "before" and "after" versions.

But note that while this is quite true, it's not likely to benefit you much in the general case because runs break at seemingly random locations in a line. So there is no guarantee your search string will occur within a single run. You will need an algorithm that locates *all* the runs containing any part of the search string, and then allocate your edits accordingly across those runs.

An empty run is valid, so `run.text == ""` may be a help when there are extra bits in the middle somewhere. Also note that runs can be formatted differently, so if part of your search string is bold and part not, for example, your results may be different than you might want.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!